# If there is a contradiction between Pratyaksha Pramana and Sabda Pramana, which one is more authoritative according to Advaita and Dvaita Vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, pramana

According to [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21235/if-there-is-a-conflict-between-pratyaksha-pramana-and-sruti-which-one-takes-pre/21238?r=SearchResults#21238) if there is a contradiction between Pratyaksha and Sruti(Like scriptures say fire is cold but we perceive fire is hot), only Pratyaksha is more authoritative according to Vishitadvaita Vedanta. I would like to know the same for Dvaita and Advaita Vedanta respectively.

Comment: But why will scriptures say something that will be against pratyaksha? Any such instances? Scriptures usually notify us abt those knowledge which are impossible for us to know by sensory methods.

Comment: Scripture says lot against pratyaksha like the wooden rod in which the cow is tied is Surya himself like the same aham brahmas