# How do different Vedantic philosophies prove the existence of the soul?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, atma, brahma-sutras, jiva

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa that summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm). In any case, in Adhyaya 3 Pada 3 of the Brahma Sutras, Vyasa says [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3797/36):

> 53. eka ātmanaḥ śarīre bhāvāt
>
> Some deny the existence of the soul, its existence being dependent on the existence of the body.
>
> 54. vyatirekastadbhāvabhāvitvānna tūpalabdhivat
>
> But this is not so; there is a distinction (between the soul and the body) because consciousness may not exist even when the body exists, as it is in the case of perception.

This translation is written from the viewpoint of the Advaita philosopher Adi Shankaracharya, who believed that Sutra 53 is presenting the view of the Charvaka school that the soul is the same as the body, and that Sutra 54 is presenting a logical argument that there exists a soul which is different from the body.

But most commentators on the Brahma Sutras do not think that these Sutras have anything to do with the soul being different from the body.  For instance Ramanujacharya thinks that these Sutras are about the fact that during meditation, one must conceive of one's own soul in its released state, not its state while inhabiting a body; see [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48435.htm) of Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya.  And Nimbarka and Srikantha Sivacharya agree with him, as you can see [here](http://gdurl.com/UoVa) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfYmr.jpg).

So my question is, how do Vedantic philosophies other than Advaita, like Dvaita, Visistadvaita, Achintya Bhedabheda, etc. prove that there exists a soul different from the body?  I'm particularly interested in whether they think Anumana or inference is sufficient to prove it, or whether Sabda Pramana or scriptural testimony is required.  Most of the Astika schools other than the Vedanta school believe it can be proven through Anumana as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22288/36).  Now as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21976/36), the Vedanta school believes that the existence of Brahman cannot be proven through Anumana, but only through Sabda Pramana.  But it may be that the existence of the Jivatma requires different means of proof than the existence of Brahman.

Comment: Why O why? Saying both "Sarvam Khalvidam Brahman" & "Brahman can't be proved" is mutually contradictory. In fact, Brahman doesn't need a proof to exist.

Comment: When you have already declared - everything is Brahman alone, then what has left to prove. 

Comment: @Rohit. To be clear, the Vedanta school agrees that statements of scripture like "Sarva Khalvidam Brahma" are the proper way to prove that Brahman exists.  It's only non-Vedantic Astika schools, like Nyaya and Vaisheshika, who think that Anumana is the proper way to prove the existence of God.

Comment: @Rohit. This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68463/discussion-on-question-by-keshav-srinivasan-how-do-different-vedantic-philosophi).

Comment: Does Madhvacharya believe the soul is different from the body? He believes there are "sattvic souls", "rajasic souls", and "tamasic souls".

Comment: @Ikshvaku Yes, of course Madhvacharya thought the soul is different from the body; he believed in the afterlife after all.  He just thought that Atmas fall into certain categories that determine their eventual destiny.

Comment: I think it's proved in Upanishads (Taittariya 2.6.1 see my edits to [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29193/277)) , before Brahma Sutra and hence not needed to be proved by particular Vedantic philosophy.

Comment: Some would try to use arthāpatti, but that has its problems (it is refutable because there is possibility of more than one postulate here and it doesn't give certain knowledge), only śabda is useful for ātman in Vedāntic schools. Or some won't prove it and say that's self evident.