# What is the distinction between yoga as Astika vs Nastika?

Tags: yoga, agamas, tantra, shad-darshana

[There are 6 orthodox (astikas) darshanas, very good explained in Keshav question here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/how-do-different-astika-schools-prove-the-existence-of-god)

At same time, yoga is based mostly on agamas or tantras, and other kind of writtings:

- [Trika philosophy have texts as Shiva Sutras, Pratyabhijña, Tantraloka, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_Shaivism)
- [Saiva Siddhanta follow Tirumantiram, Tiruvacakam, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaiva_Siddhanta)
- [Nath Sampradaya have Goraksha shatakam, Siddha Siddhanta Paddhati, Shiva Samhita, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nath)

Then, this Tantric Yoga, could not be one of 6 darshanas.

So, is there a clear distinction between astika yoga, and tantrik yoga on scriptures? Both of then have same name (yoga)? Or is there a different name or another way to distinguish them?