# Are there ways to count tithis that differs from traditional astrology?

Tags: yoga, astrology, tantra

Are there some text (specially tantras, agamas, nigamas, others) which explain how to count tithi in a different way to Vedic Jyotish?

Traditionally, fortnight start day after purnima (full moon) or amavasya (new moon). So certain dates as Vasant Panchami, should fall on day 5 after amavasya (it would be, amavasya, then day 1, then day 2, day 3, day 4, panchami), or ekadasi should fall on day 11 after full or new moon (purnima, then day 1, day 2, day 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10, ekadasi).

But once, I heard that, the counting should start from purnima (or amavasya) itself, so according to that, Vasant Panchami should be: amavasya, then day 2, day 3, 4, panchami (1 day before than traditional). And same with ekadasi of course.

Is there some scripture explaining this?

For example ISKCON has a very profound way to calculate ekadasi, because fasting on dashami is considered very very inauspicious, and they have a lot of regulation as to how the proper day should be calculated . But they count in the traditional way. Counting in this yogic way I'm asking, ekadashi would fall on ISKCON's dashami.

Comment: What is Tantrik Yoga? By Yoga are u meaning that Yoga which is one of the Panchangas?

Comment: @Rickross I meaning yoga system, but tantrik, like Nath Sampradaya Yoga, or Saiva Siddhanta, or Trika, etc. Maybe I should edit my question? "how to properly count tithi acording to tantras, agamas, nigamas" ??

Comment: There are no such diverse systems of Yoga..If i sit in the Padmasana posture then by that i am not converting myself to a Tantric or a Vaidik or whatever.. These postures are the same irrespective of anything.. This is about Hatha YOga..same for higher forms of Yoga.. BTW it's the Tantric scriptures only where Yoga has been extensively dealt with..

Comment: @Rickross Ok, then, [can you answer here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24208/what-is-the-distinction-between-yoga-as-astika-vs-nastika)

Comment: I do not know how to answer that Q.. and this is actually the first time i have ever seen someone discriminating Yoga like that.. Yoga is the same.. Eventually it means the union of Jivatman with the Paramatman..And, while other scriptures have just hinted about it the Tantric scriptures have dealt with it thoroughly.

Comment: There are some yajñas made in some way according to veda, and other different way according to tantra. Sometimes difference are small (just including bija mantras), sometimes bigger. There are some different points of view in philosophy also. Is true that yoga is "hinted" in vedic writtings, and "more dealed" in tantra, but also there is some diferences. Bhagavad gita is "yoga shashtra", all full book, but there is explained more about yoga of inner attitudes. Yoga is not alwasy including asanas, and certainly not always about hatha.

Comment: There is laya yoga, mantra yoga, or even nidra yoga (tantrik derivation from nyasa), and even more, in what I called "tantrik yoga". There is alchemy in saiva siddhanta, or yoga of cycles and nature understanding (muhurtas), and svarodhaya, and even more. All of this whitout asanas and hatha, but all of this having foundation on tantras and/or vedas, and sometimes there are differences based on that. [My question here deals about all of these](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24208/what-is-the-distinction-between-yoga-as-astika-vs-nastika).

Comment: Just an example, take Karma Yoga: you can understand karma yoga in a way to perform your actions without feeling of doer. Or with feeling of doing as offering to God. Or with feeling of whatever is happening just happen. Or you can keep your atention on Atma and let the body-mind does his work. There is also one point of view with call karma yoga to ritualistic actions, so you are doing karma yoga when you perform your rituals. One yoga and many points of view. But also you can do Karma yoga when your body performs some actions when you invited a Shakti Devi, and allow her to use your body.

Comment: My question here (tithis) deal about differences on tithi counting way, according to veda and tantra (mostly).

Comment: Ok i have understood ur Q here.. but i don't know the answer.. as regards the other Q there.. that is also difficult to answer for me.. as i have told all the scriptures have just hinted on Yoga.. but Tantras have dealt with it thoroughly.. So, Tantra and Yoga are deeply related.. Also it is not that easy to differentiate like that..because it's a difficult task to show whether a Tantra is following Veda or not.. BTW by Astika u mean who believes in Veda or who believes in the existence of God?

Comment: By Astika I mean believe in Veda. I mean "orthodox" clasification of 6 darshans.