# "gods"what is the most striking, conspicious and visible proof of the presence of God?

Tags: gods

" gods"
what is the most striking, conspicious and visible proof of the presence of God?

Comment: You & me typing this ..

Comment: I'm also another one

Comment: Jokes apart. External gods are often impossible to prove. Also, only a few darshanas (or philosophies) do prescribe that. There are *'godless'* interpretations of Vedanta to deal with it. Some of them are extended to tantras too. Go through this answer, I answered earlier: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57803/29449

Comment: @User29449 ,None of the vendanta sampradaya had ever given a Godless interpretation. (this Paramarthika idea  should not be mixed up across the other orders of reality). Gita says Godless interpretation is  an asuric notion , 16.8 **The world is without Absolute Truth, without any basis (for moral order), and without a God (who has created or is controlling it). It is created from the combination of the two sexes, and has no purpose other than desire gratification**

Comment: @Athrey Read my reply carefully, **externally godless**, you need to fix your basics - Go and read mahavakyas, the supreme brahman is *sakshi*.

Comment: @Athrey you are partly correct in Vedanta there has always been a god actively interacting with the universe. But, the issue comes now in regards to Brahman. Both Dviata and Visistadvaita believe in Sanguna Brahman or a defied version of divine bliss and the absolute truth ie Vishnu. Advaita believes more in Brahman as a concept or supreme reality with Ishvara holding significance idk their exact relation though.

Comment: @Athrey that being said the Bhagavad Gita verse talks in terms of men of lust and evil nature which no Astika Darshana is. Many of them hold Ishvara, or god's existence while some are neutral on the stance. The difference is the method or use of Ishvara and how he plays in giving us salvation. Many other Darshanas accept a more deistic god from my research or a vaguer concept. Minamsa is the only school which isn't even atheistic just suggest proving god isn't needed to show the authority of the Vedas.

Comment: @User29449 I couldn't make it straight away, by relating **godless interpretations of Vedanta** with the External God .I apologise  for any misinterpretation.Also Im nt making any  claims of erudition/ scholarliness in the subject.To my knowledge, an Atheist is a samshyatma (who doubts the teaching/ in possession of tamasa jnana(partial  consciousness),thus can't benifit the ascent of consciousness  to eventualy discover the internal antaryami God in hridya guhya .Yoga school do mention *Ishvara Pranidana*.Sri Shankara clearly establishes Ishwara in Brahma Sutra bhashya contending sankya .

Comment: @User29449 , The very first sloka of Isa vasya **īśā vāsyamidagaṁ sarvaṁ yatkiñca jagatyaṁ jagat** lays emphasis on the idea God pervades the universe.Mimaamsa is more focused on ritual system , the cause /effect patterns as per Vedas, So Vedanta is more authoritative than Mimaamsa with regards to Brahma tattva , which is its own subject matter, not the subject matter of Mimaamsa.Only karma and it's retribution matters to them, so is Logic/reasoning to Nyaya.

Comment: @User29449,  All schools show concerns over bondage and liberation in its own context , nonetheless Vedanta is more authoritative on matters of personal God /Ishwara

Comment: @Haridasa ,True , However, to my knowledge Advaita does not deny the fact of Ishwara / Krama mukti (in  its own order of reality ,the context of Maya,Adyasa) But it more emphatic on Impersonal Brahman,/ Jivan mukti / sadyo mukti as it confers absolute liberation

Comment: @ Milap Goud: God is everywhere and particularly nowhere. He  is in an insect, animal, flower flowing wind or water or body blood and brain cells. He is available  through sensing and guessing , through Bhakthi address in the moving( chara) and static (achara) states. Conveniently made by Man in a Sthoola shape, He is made available in places of worship kept much above the Man to guide, help and regulate his own life.

Answer (score -1):

A fragment of Virat Swaroop of God, to an extent one can see of, whatever is around the individual, is the most striking, conspicious and visible proof of the presence of God

But one should rise beyond what is obvious to truly experience the presence of  God.

(To draw an analogy) say to a calling bell(electrical).., only the mechanics portion (ie. the clapper hitting the gong / noise) is conspicuous., contrasted to it's cause the electromagnetic force/field .In the same way, the energy fields causing the movement of whatever is conspicuous,  aren't conspicuous by themselves , they can only be  known  through the visible(conspicuous ) effects they produce.

If one considers only the fragmental portion of truth (conspicuous in nature)to be holistic in itself , Gita says such a knowledge (jnana) that has occured is Tamasik Jnana

> That knowledge is said to be in the mode of ignorance where one is engrossed in a fragmental concept as if it encompasses the whole, and which is neither grounded in reason nor based on the truth.(Swami Mukundananda) Gita 18.22

> The truths of religion, as God and Soul, cannot be perceived by the external senses. I cannot see God with my eyes, nor can I touch Him with my hands, and we also know that neither can we reason beyond the senses.We may reason all our lives, as the world has been doing for thousands of years, and the result is that we find we are incompetent to prove or disprove the facts of religion. Man has in him the faculty, the power, of transcending his intellect even, and that power is in every being. By the practice of Yoga that power is aroused, and then man transcends the ordinary limits of reason, and directly perceives things which are beyond all reason.(Swami Vivekananda)

It is only when bhakti translates  into Para bhakti , tattvam/ truth of the God is known .

> bhaktyā mām abhijānāti yāvān yaśh chāsmi tattvataḥ
> tato māṁ tattvato jñātvā viśhate tad-anantaram
> Only by loving devotion to Me does one come to know who I am in Truth. Then, having come to know Me, My devotee enters into full consciousness of Me( BG 18.55)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so let's suppose there is no God.

Our life ends and brain is switched off forever like a computer that has been crashed and no soul exists. But this is denied by many researches.

First example :[Shanti devi](https://www.carolbowman.com/dr-ian-stevenson/case-shanti-devi)

A  [Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Cases_Suggestive_of_Reincarnation) that also hold this claim: Twenty Cases Suggestive of Reincarnation By by Ian Stevenson

```
Another Proof of God
```

God is one from whom everything originates, on whose support everything depends, and to whom everything returns (see Taittirīya Upaniṣad 3.1-6, Brahma-Sūtra 1.1.2).

Taittirīya Upaniṣad (2.6.1):

असन्नेव स भवति, असद्‌ब्रह्मेति वेद चेत् ।

“If a person knows Brahman as nonexistent, he himself becomes nonexistent.”

Chāndogya Upaniṣad (3.14.1):

सर्वं खलु इदं ब्रह्म ।

“All this is indeed Brahman.”

Your own consciousness is indeed [undeniable](https://youtu.be/K660oqHBLrw?feature=shared) proof of God

```
When will I know, beyond any doubt, 
that God exists
```

Absolute certainty about God’s existence is possible only through a direct experience (aparokṣa anubhūti) of God. Such experiences are possible and, when they occur, all doubts about God vanish (Muṇḍaka Upaniṣad 2.2.8, Bhāgavata 1.2.21), all fear vanishes (Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 4.2.4), everything that constricts freedom vanishes for ever. Once I experience God in that way, no one in the universe can persuade me that God doesn’t exist?