# Birth after enjoying all good deeds in Heaven

Tags: belief, gods, bhagavad-gita, karma

If a person does many good deeds in his life. There are very few say 25% bad deeds in his life.

If he enjoys all the fruits of his 75% good deeds in heaven.

Then which kind of family he gets born?

In rich family ? Or Poor / Bad family ? (for getting fruits of 25% bad deeds)

Please clarify.

Comment: It is very difficult to tell when a given action will bear fruit.  Sometimes it bears fruit five minutes from now, sometimes it bears fruit a thousand births from now.  So what birth you will have after you die will not just be determined by the actions you are doing in this birth, but also the actions you've done in past births as well.

Comment: You may be interested in the excerpt from Bhatta Ramakantha's work quoted in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10706/36 It has to do with the fact that all the actions that a person does in one birth cannot possibly all bear fruit within a single lifetime.

Comment: @Sagar You might find some answers in this YouTube video: [Law of Karma is not Eye-for-Eye](https://youtu.be/4-7w7mLy6ck)

Comment: It is important to note that even highest position in heaven in not permanent , so seek for the eternal truth moksha (liberation). As keshav srinivasan told you it is impossible to predict the maturity period of karma. Also I agree with sv. on "Law of karma is not-eye-for-eye" title. Law of karma is set to know that every action has fruits associated with it so act according to dharma. Its like law enforcement for all jivas to follow dharma.

Comment: @sv. video was too much scientific :D

Comment: As far as I know one can get into heaven only if he has 100% of good deeds and 0% of bad (evil, sinful) deeds. And if he has 75% of good deeds and 25% of bad (evil, sinful) deeds, as you said, he can not even reach the heaven world.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa that would be impossible for any human being to have 100% good deeds. At some point of time knowing or unknowingly human nature do commits sins

Comment: @Sagar Yeah you are right, eventually everyone will commit some sin, but still it is true that even such a person can be of 100% of good deeds and 0% of bad (evil, sinful) deeds! How is that possible? He can atone for all his sins, and cleansed of all the sins he can be elevated to the heaven world. And only like that he can ascend into the heaven, with no sins.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa interesting... how the sins can be cleaned? Altogether with different topic .. but please answer .. how can commited sins can be destroyed ?

Comment: @Sagar Well, there are several verses in the Bhagavad gita that talk about either how the sins can be destroyed, or how one can live unaffected by the previous sins. See for example verses 4.37; 4.41; 6.27 and 28; 5.10 and 17. Especially pay attention to the verse 4.37 which says that all karma can be destroyed: http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/37 In the verse 18.71 it is even said that those who listen the Bhagavad gita with faith and without envy become free from sinful reactions and attain to heaven. I suggest you to read those verses with word for word translation at www.vedabase.com/en/bg

Comment: @brahmajijnasa That is interesting blog

Comment: More about that in the chat *Discussion between Keshav Srinivasan and brahma jijnasa*: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29877661#29877661

Answer (score 1):

if he don't have enough punya to be a man then that soul after heavenly pleasures take birth again of ants donkeys pigs etc. 84 lakh kinds of births...human body is greater than of gods as only we can do karma & attain salvation...so it needs way big punya or god's mercy to be a man...we all have become indra & then again ant rat pig etc. that too uncountable times!:)