# Why Devraj Indra was chosen as the king of the Devas?

Tags: indra, gods

How Devraj Indra became the king of all Devas? I mean how and why he was chosen as the king?

Comment: Indra is post. Anyone (jiva) can become Indra. Those who perform 100 Ashwamedha Yagnas  are eligible in next life.

Comment: Related [Story of Purandara Indra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7234/3500).

Comment: If Indra is a post then who was the 1st Indra?

Comment: There have been many Indras, and there's no first as time is cyclic. Name of Indra of present Manvanatara (Vaivaswara) is Purandara.

Comment: I heard that Hanuman got offer of Indra's post by SaptRishi in his childhood but Hanuman politely refused it.

Comment: One question unrelated to this. I heard that Yama is also a post. The man who died 1st was 1st Yama. Is that true?

Comment: Those who perform 100 Ashwamedha Yagnas are eligible as INDRA in next life then what happens to INDRA who is currently in position.

Comment: And if there are more than one eligible people for the post of Indra then what is the procedure to choose one?

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad When new Indra replace old one then he continues his work which was being done by him earlier or currently. For example, Current Indra is God of rain. His responsibility is to make rain on Earth on time. Some day he has to leave his Indra's post, then even if he will not be king even then He will continue to perform his duties (rain) like other Gods (wind god, fire god etc.) are doing. He has to leave his responsibilities of King, But responsibility of Raining will remain.

Comment: @Rishabh If I want to be eligible for post of INDRA then do i need be be God of something like wind, fire, earth or something.

Comment: @PraveenGaikwad Why you need to be God? It is not necessary. A human can also be a King. Let me give you an example... San in-law of Shiva (who was human) was also chosen for Indra's post for certain amount of time. He was eligible for that post coz he has done many great yagya. Don't remeber the name of yagya and quantity but what ever he did that was enough for the Indra's post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **How Indra became king of Gods?**

Actually Indra is not the name of any  one person rather it’s a post of King of heaven and  king of demi gods.

On performing some  sacrifices number of times or penances , any man can go to heaven and can obtain  position of the king of heaven Or king of gods.  For e.g. **doing   Hundred 
 Ashwamedha Yajnas  one can attain the post of Indra.**   He will retain the post of Indra  until   another person  does more Or Same Yajnas  than previous Indra  and becomes eligible for this position.

This is described in [**Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section -20**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a020.htm)

> यज्ञाय सृष्टानि धनानि धात्रा; यष्टादिष्टः पुरुषॊ रक्षिता च
>  तस्मात
>   सर्वं यज्ञ एवॊपयॊज्यं; धनं ततॊ ऽनन्तर एव कामः
>  **यज्ञैर इन्द्रॊ
>   विविधैर अन्नवद्भिर; देवान सर्वान अभ्ययान महौजाः**
>  तेनेन्द्रत्वं
>   पराप्य विभ्राजते ऽसौ; तस्माद यज्ञे सर्वम एवॊपयॊज्यम
>  महादेवः
>   सर्वमेधे महात्मा; हुत्वात्मानं देवदेवॊ विभूतः
>  विश्वाँल लॊकान
>   वयाप्य विष्टभ्य कीर्त्या; विरॊचते दयुतिमान कृत्ति वासाः
>  आविक्षितः
>   पार्थिवॊ वै मरुत्तः; सवृद्ध्या मर्त्यॊ यॊ ऽयजद देवराजम
>  यज्ञे यस्य
>   शरीः सवयं संनिविष्टा; यस्मिन भाण्डं काञ्चनं सर्वम आसीत
>   हरिश्चन्द्रः पार्थिवेन्द्रः शरुतस ते; यज्ञैर इष्ट्वा पुण्यकृद
>   वीतशॊकः
>  ऋद्ध्या शक्रं यॊ ऽजयन मानुषः संस; तस्माद यज्ञे सर्वम
>   एवॊपयॊज्यम
>
> yajñāya sṛṣṭāni dhanāni dhātrā; yaṣṭādiṣṭaḥ puruṣo rakṣitā ca
>   tasmāt sarvaṃ yajña evopayojyaṃ; dhanaṃ tato 'nantara eva kāmaḥ
>   **yajñair indro vividhair annavadbhir; devān sarvān abhyayān
>   mahaujāḥ**
>  tenendratvaṃ prāpya vibhrājate 'sau; tasmād yajñe sarvam
>   evopayojyam
>  mahādevaḥ sarvamedhe mahātmā; hutvātmānaṃ devadevo
>   vibhūtaḥ
>  viśvāṁl lokān vyāpya viṣṭabhya kīrtyā; virocate dyutimān
>   kṛtti vāsāḥ
>  āvikṣitaḥ pārthivo vai maruttaḥ; svṛddhyā martyo yo
>   'yajad devarājam
>  yajñe yasya śrīḥ svayaṃ saṃniviṣṭā; yasmin
>   bhāṇḍaṃ kāñcanaṃ sarvam āsīt
>  hariścandraḥ pārthivendraḥ śrutas te;
>   yajñair iṣṭvā puṇyakṛd vītaśokaḥ
>  ṛddhyā śakraṃ yo 'jayan mānuṣaḥ
>   saṃs; tasmād yajñe sarvam evopayojyam
>
> The exercise of the duty of charity after discriminating the deserving
>   from the undeserving is not easy. The Supreme Ordainer created wealth
>   for sacrifice, and He created man also for taking care of that wealth
>   and for performing sacrifice. For this reason the whole of one's
>   wealth should be applied to sacrifice. Pleasure would follow from it
>   as a natural consequence. Possessed of abundant energy, **Indra, by
>   the performance of diverse sacrifices with profuse gifts of valuables,
>   surpassed all the gods. Having got their chiefship by that means, he
>   shineth in heaven.** Therefore, everything should be applied to
>   sacrifices.
>
> ---

This is also described  in **Shreemad Bhagavt Purana**

> अथादीक्षत राजा तु हयमेधशतेन स : |
>  ब्रह्मावर्तो मनो: क्षेत्रे यत्र
>   प्राची सरस्वती ||1||
>
> athādīkṣata rājā tu  hayamedha-śatena saḥ
>  brahmāvarte manoḥ kṣetre
>   yatra prācī sarasvatī
>
> The great sage Maitreya continued: My dear Vidura, **King Pṛthu
>   initiated the performance of one hundred horse sacrifices** at the
>   spot where the river Sarasvatī flows towards the east. This piece of
>   land is known as Brahmāvarta, and it was controlled by Svāyambhuva
>   Manu.[**SB 4.19.1**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/19/1)
>
> तदभिप्रेत्य भगवान् कर्मातिशयमात्मन:| 
>  शतक्रतुर्न ममृषे
>   पृथोर्यज्ञमहोत्सवम् ||2||
>
> tad abhipretya bhagavān karmātiśayam ātmanaḥ  
>  śata-kratur na
>   mamṛṣe pṛthor yajña-mahotsavam
>
> When the most powerful Indra, the King of heaven, saw this, he
>   considered the fact that King Pṛthu was going to exceed him in
>   fruitive activities. Thus Indra could not tolerate the great
>   sacrificial ceremonies performed by King Pṛthu.[**SB 4.19.2**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/19/2)
>
> **Purport:** This envy is also found in the personality of the King of heaven, Indra. As evident from revealed scriptures, Indra was several
>   times envious of many persons. He was especially envious of great
>   fruitive activities and the execution of yoga practices, or siddhis.
>   Indeed, he could not tolerate them, and he desired to break them up.
>   **He was envious due to fear that those who performed great sacrifices for the execution of mystic yoga might occupy his seat.**

---

[**The Kena Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145062.html) – Kahanda -4  - Verse 28 , tells us why Indra became superior to all the gods. By knowing Brahman first. Here is the brief story-

> The Brahman won a victory for the Devas and in that victory of the
>   Brahman the Devas attained glory. They thought ‘the victory is ours
>   and this glory is ours alone.’ He knew this notion of theirs and
>   appeared before them. What that Great Spirit was they did not know.
>   The devas addressed the Fire thus “O Jataveda! Find out what this
>   Great Spirit is. - Then That  Brahman placed a straw before him and
>   said: ‘Burn this , but Agni (Jataveda!)  was not able to burn it. Then
>   the devas said Vayu: “Learn O Vayu! what this Great Spirit is” –
>   Brahman  That placed a straw before him and said “Blow it away , but
>   vayu but was not able to blow it.  But afterwards Indra  approached
>   Brahman and he disappeared , then Indra saw Uma (Parvati) and he asked
>   about him to her , then Uma said to Indra  -“It is Brahman indeed.
>   Attain glory in the victory of Brahman.” From her words only, he
>   learned that it was Brahman.” Therefore also does Indra considerably
>   excel other Devas.
>
> ---
>
> तस्माद्वा इन्द्रोऽतितरामिवान्यान्देवान्स ह्येनन्नेदिष्ठं पस्पर्श स
>   ह्येनत्प्रथमो विदाञ्चकार ब्रह्मेति ॥ २८ ॥
>
> tasmādvā
>   indro'titarāmivānyāndevānsa hyenannediṣṭhaṃ pasparśa sa hyenatprathamo
>   vidāñcakāra brahmeti || 28 ||
>
> 28. Therefore also does Indra considerably excel other Devas because he approached Brahman nearest and because he first knew the Spirit to
>       be Brahman.

Comment: Asking just for curiosity, One can become king of Heaven just by defeating Indra? Because many had become king of Heaven by defeating Indra. Some examples of them are Tadkasur, Jalndhar and some other. They both were King of heaven (Indra) until their death. So it is also applicable way go get heaven by strength?

Comment: Defeating Indra is not a easy task. Even just to challenge him ,one must posses equal or more strength  , equal divine weapons/, equal tejas. and apart from that one should posses the siddhi to reach to heaven in order to fight and to defeat him. So most of the kings just performed 100 Ashwamedha Yajnas here on earth.

Comment: I will search Puranas and will give you more about this in time :)