# "Indra is the position of being the king of the gods which changes in every Manvantara": What does this mean?

Tags: indra

Does the above sentence mean that the same God is not identified as "Indra" in every manvantara?

Comment: Yes, it is similar to prime minister or any other position.

Comment: @hanugm who is the current indra then?

Comment: [Purandara or Sakra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7234/story-of-purandara-indra).

Comment: @hanugm Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indra is a position and occupied by different people at various times. Please see [Narada purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-narada-purana/d/doc57546.html) for the list of manvantaras and the indra of each manvantara.

> “I will first tell you about the manvantaras,” replied Sudharma.
>
> There are fourteen such eras in one of Brahma’s days. Each such era is
> ruled over by a Manu. And the gods also change from one manvantara to
> another. In addition, the title of Indra changes hands.
>
> The first Manu was Svayambhuva. The gods were then the yamas and the
> Indra was Shachipati.,
>
> The second Manu was Svarochisha. The gods were the paravatas and
> tushitas and the Indra was Vipashchita.
>
> The third Manu was Uttama. The gods were the sudhamas, satyas, shivas
> and pratardanas and the Indra was Sushanti.
>
> The fourth Manu was Tamasa. The gods were the surupas, haris, suptas
> and sudhis and the Indra was Shibi.
>
> The fifth Manu was Raivata. The gods were the amitabhas and the Indra
> was Ribhu
>
> The sixth Manu was Chakshusha. The gods were the adyas and the Indra
> was Manojava.
>
> **The seventh manu was Vaivasvata. This is the manvantara that is now
> current. The gods are the adityas, vasus and rudras and the Indra is
> Purandara.**
>
> There will be seven more manvantaras before the destruction.
>
> The eighth Manu will Suryasavarni. The gods will be the sutapas and
> the Indra will be Vali.
>
> The ninth manu will be Dakshasavarni. The gods will be the paravatas
> and the Indra will be Adbhuta.
>
> The tenth manu will be Brahmasavarni. The gods will be the vamanas and
> the Indra will be Shanti.
>
> The eleventh Manu will be Dharmasavarni. The gods will be the
> vihangamas and the Indra will be Vrisha.
>
> The twelfth manu will be Rudrasavarni. The gods will be the haritas
> and the Indra will be Ritadhama.
>
> The thirteenth Manu will be Rouchya. The gods will be the sutramas and
> the Indra will be Divaspati.
>
> The fourteenth Manu will be Bhoutya. The gods will be the chakshushas
> and the Indra will be Shuchi.