# What are examples of entities who are worshiped in temples and are not Gods or Devas?

Tags: subhadra

An example is Subhadra who is worshiped at Puri.

This post gives her some kind of divinity

[Was Subhadra also an avatar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3437/was-subhadra-also-an-avatar)

Are there other temples besides Puri Jagannath where the entity being worshiped is not a God/Goddess/Deva explicitly mentioned in canonical Sanskrit scripture?

Comment: Regarding Subhadra, there is a little confusion. The term 'Subhadra' is a generic term & can't be taken to mean Arjuna's wife & Abhimanyu's mother by default. Under the guise of Subhadra it is actually Ekanamsha, the incarnation of Vishnu's Yogamaya who manifested as Nanda-Yashoda's daughter, who is worshipped in Puri.

Comment: Ah yes - the famous "no proper names in Sanskrit" argument .@অনু

Answer (score 1):

Jatayu was not a God, As far as i know (Rama gave him Moksha, I believe).

https://rameshwaramtourism.co.in/jatayu-tirtham-temple-rameshwaram

is dedicated to Jatayu.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaitheeswaran_Koil has a shrine to Jatayu.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things worshipped in temples that are not devas, but however, have some divine association (like: the holy place (tirtha), snakes (nagas), the mount of the gods (vahana), guards of the temple (dwarpal), etc.). Depending on the sampradaya one is from, they are seen as a manifestation of god himself, or very dear to the lord, hence mandated to be worshipped. In some temples, even devotees of gods are worshipped. Again, it can be interpreted as devotee = god or very dear to god, so we worship.

Hopefully, that answers your question. Forgive me if I made any mistakes or if the writing is poor.